# Compact sets on $\sigma$-algebra and nested classes statement

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{K}$ be a compact set and $\mathcal{K} \subset \mathcal{A}$ - a $\sigma$-algebra. Also, let $A_n$ be a sequence of nested classes: $A_{n+1} \subset A_{n}, \cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i = \emptyset, i\neq j$. A measure is also given that has the property of "approachig compact class" (not exactly sure how this translates from Russian) (let me know if you want me to give a definition of this). (Also note that $K_n \subset A_n$ and that $\cap_{i=1}^NK_i = \emptyset$)

The notes define $A_N$ as:
$$\cap_{i=1}^N A_i$$

They then state that:

> $$\cap_{i=1}^N A_i \subset \cup_{i=1}^N A_i \backslash K_i$$

And I fail to see this. $K_i$ is meant to be an element of the compact class and should be a "close representative" of $A_i$, so the difference should produce a set with pretty much nothing in it. I could see why this would be the case:

$$\cap_{i=1}^N A_i \subset \cup_{i=1}^N A_i$$

Because the sequence $\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of nested classes, so you have less and less elements. Thus, it makes sense that the union is larger. But given the above statement, it is natural to think that if you take something out of the set then:
$$\cup_{i=1}^N A_i \backslash K_i \subset \cup_{i=1}^N A_i$$

But this still does not help me understand their statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note that $\bigcap_{i=1}^N A_i=A_N$ since $A_i\downarrow$.

Let $x\in A_N$. Since $\bigcap_iK_i=\emptyset$, there exists a $j\leq N$ such that $x\notin K_j$. Together with $A_j\supset A_N$ follows $x\in A_j\setminus K_j$ which shows the inclusion $A_N\subset \bigcup_iA_i\setminus K_i$